# window.open every 5 min onload (javascript)

Tags: javascript, onload, setinterval, window.open

hi Im pretty much a beginner. I need some help putting this together in javascript, I want it to open a new window every 5 minutes without having to click a button at anytime. TY

```
window.open( "http://www.google.com/" )

setInterval(function, 60000);

onload=
```

Comment: first result in google of "setInterval onload" and also a [repeated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162267/setinterval-and-window-onload-problem)

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    window.open( "http://www.google.com/" );
  }, 300000) // 5 min
};
```

Though what you are doing isn't going to be user friendly in any way unless you are doing some sort of experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="setTimeout("window.location=''",300000)">
```