# jQuery setInterval() undefined function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am relatively new to javascript and jQuery and while trying to create a function the runs in intervals of 100 milliseconds I encountered a problem.I seem to get in the console of firebug and error witch says that clasing() is not defined.This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var prev = $("img.selected").prev();
    var curent = $("img.selected");
    var next =  $("img.selected").next().length ? $("img.selected").next() : $("img:first");

    $("img").not(":first").css("display","none");

    function clasing() {
        curent.removeClass("selected");
        next.addClass("selected");
    }

    setInterval("clasing()",100);
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162267/setinterval-and-window-onload-problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a scope problem. Your variables (`prev`, `curent` and `next`) are accessible inside `.ready` scope, such as your function `clasing`. But when you add this function to be called in a interval, using `setInterval`, this function should be in a Global scope (inside `window` object). Then, you should declare this function like `window.clasing = function(){ ... }`, but, doing this, the variables declared in `.ready()` scope will not be accessible running the function outside this scope, so all your variables must be in a global scope too. This should solve your problem.

However, this isn't a good programming practice, you should declare your variables inside `clasing` function, then they will be accessible only in function scope; And your function must be delcared outside `.ready()` function, and then you declare the interval inside `.ready()` function.

So, your code should be liek this:

```
function clasing(){
  var prev = $("img.selected").prev();
  var curent = $("img.selected");
  var next =  $("img.selected").next().length ? $("img.selected").next() : $("img:first");

  curent.removeClass("selected");
  next.addClass("selected");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").not(":first").css("display","none");
  setInterval("clasing()",100);  //or just setInterval(clasing,100);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `setInterval("clasing()",100);` to `setInterval(clasing,100);`

Comment: Well, it's a good advise, not an answer... There is "overload" with string that parsed with `eval`

Comment: @eval passing the function reference instead of a string will fix the scope issue. see [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162267/setinterval-and-window-onload-problem)

Comment: it isn't the answer... both `setInterval('clasing()',100)` and `setInterval(clasing,100)` will trigger an error of undefined function since the problem is about the function scope..

Comment: @NickBeranek of course the scope is an issue.. if all variables would declared inside the function to be updated in each execution, the setInterval will continue to trigger the undefined function error, since clasing was declared inside `.ready` and `setInterval('someName')` try to execute a global function called 'someName'

Comment: No, you're right, hence why I deleted that comment. I was blinded by the variables and should've paid attention.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
setInterval("clasing()",100);
```

To

```
setInterval(function() {
     clasing();
 }, 100);
```

Right now your call to setInterval is running in global scope, but your function is defined inside your jquery function. Creating a closure will give you access to the jquery functions members.